# How to count unique text values in a range, with some constraints given?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, I have a range cells:

```
Date        Number
04/1/2019     A1
07/1/2019     A2
14/1/2019     -
15/1/2019     A1
02/2/2019     A3
07/2/2019     A1
```

and I want to count the amount of unique number in January, which is 2. What should I do? I am using anolder version of Excel, whcich does not support functions such as FILTER() and UNIQUE().
I have found a formula online:

```
{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(data<>"", MATCH(data,data,0)),ROW(data)-ROW(data.firstcell)+1),1))}
```

which can count unique text values in a range which ignoring blank cells. However, I was unable to modify it to suit my usage, since it doesn't allow me to insert any criteria (such as date and ignore "-"). Most of the solution online involves functions such as FILTER() and UNIQUE(), which I am not able to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Slight modification of your attempt in `D1`, based on [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria) handy website:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((B2:B7<>"-")*(MONTH(A2:A7)=1),MATCH(B2:B7,B2:B7,0)),ROW(B2:B7)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

Entered as array formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

This boolean logic allows you to enter many more criteria if needed, such as `YEAR` if your dates can span more than the year 2019 and you need to filter on that too. Or include a check against empty values. It's very versatile.

Comment: Nice solution @JvdV

Comment: Oh yes! That's the website I was referenced to, but I never thought to combine 2 of the formulas together, thanks!

Comment: @Alex, if you scroll down you'll notice the explaination about the boolean logic. Glad it helped.